# Force \qed to break margin

Tags: margins

I'm trying to add

```
 \qed
```

to the end of a proof on my homework, but the proof comes so close to the bottom of the page the symbol is being put at the start of the next page.  Is there a way to force it to the previous page and break the margin?  Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
 \begin{align*}
 \text{Minimize: }z=3x_1+x_2
 \end{align*}
 subject to
 \begin{align*}
 x_1-e_1&=3\\
 x_1+x_2+s_1&=4\\
 2x_1-x_2&=3\\[.5 em]
 x_1\geq 0; \hspace{.5cm} x_2\geq 0; \hspace{.5cm} e_1&\geq 0; \hspace{.5cm}
 s_1\geq 0
 \end{align*}\qed
```

[image]

Comment: If you use `proof`, then use `\qedhere` at the end of the last line in the alignment.

Comment: Otherwise resort to `\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}`.

Comment: Btw use `\quad` instead of `\hspace{...} `, that command is hardly ever a good choice in math.

Comment: I like that, @daleif, I haven't seen that before.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: It is a good measure to base all hspaces on in math mode, `\qquad=2\quad` and `\enspace=0.5\quad` (though I'm never sure if one should use `\enspace ` or `\enskip`